# Burp Suite upstream proxy

Tags: appsec, proxy, burp-suite

Is there a way to configure burpsuite's upstream proxy direct the traffic to the local box's proxy configuration? Additionally is there a way to exclude urls from being directed to the upstream proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upstream proxies can be configured in "User options" -> "Connections".

[image: Burp Suite Upstream Proxy Settings]

Excluding URL's works a bit different. You basically tell the upstream proxy what URL's you want to go through that proxy or you enter a URL without an upstream proxy (leave blank)

[image]